# Getting a specific value from a json response

Tags: php, laravel-7

I have this code

```
$client = json_decode($client); 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($client);
```

which produces there

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Jojohn@doe.com
        [email_verified_at] => 
        [password] => $2y$10$pAvJ9/K7ZPOqw10WhfmToumK0TY1XihY8M9uAEEs4GkHZr4LdGc4e
        [remember_token] => 
        [created_at] => 2020-07-29 21:08:02
        [updated_at] => 
        [userid] => 2
        [account_rep] => 3
    )

)
```

My question is how do I get the value of name and account_rep I tried

```
echo $client['0']['object']['name'];
```

but that does not work it just throws an error

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_decode($variable), is used to decode or convert a JSON object to a PHP object.

So you could do this as `$client['0']` is an object.

```
echo $client['0']->name;
```

But I'd say you should rather convert the json object to **associative array** instead of PHP object by passing `TRUE` to as an argument to the json_decode. When `TRUE`, returned objects get converted into associative arrays.

```
$client = json_decode($client, true);
```

Now $client is

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Jojohn@doe.com
        [email_verified_at] => 
        [password] => $2y$10$pAvJ9/K7ZPOqw10WhfmToumK0TY1XihY8M9uAEEs4GkHZr4LdGc4e
        [remember_token] => 
        [created_at] => 2020-07-29 21:08:02
        [updated_at] => 
        [userid] => 2
        [account_rep] => 3
    )

)
```

Now you could simply do

```
echo $client[0]['name'];
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example on what to change

Comment: Hey! I've updated the solution. I've changed the `$client['name']` to `$client[0]['name']`. I'm sorry I forgot to add it earlier :)